# Problem with text color in snackbar KivyMd

Tags: kivy, kivymd, snackbar

I read kivymd Snackbar documentation where they say that i can change text color in this way.

```py
Snackbar(text="[color=181818]Elemento copiato negli appunti![/color]").show()
```

But when I execute it this is the result:

[image: 1]

So the color hasn't changed, and it shows the color code with square brackets in the text.

Comment: Try `[color=#181818]`.

Comment: It's the same thing. The color doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text color like this:

```
    sb = Snackbar(text='Elemento copiato negli appunti!')
    sb.ids.text_bar.text_color = get_color_from_hex('181818')
    sb.show()
```

But this only allows a single color for the entire text.